# Folding electrical circuit section wise

Tags: circuit-analysis

> Simplfy the following circuit:
> [image]

My try:
[image]

The easy way to do this is seeing no current passes through across the branch (2,5,8) and hence we can remove it. However, I was trying to combine parallel branches and running into trouble.

Notice that 1 is same potential at 7 and 2 is same potential as 8, I got that I can combine resistor at between 1-2 and 7-8 but I can't seem to figure out the conenctivity of resulting circuit after I combine both.

However, if I combine the lower half and upper half at same time then it's easy for me to visualize (aka folding a circuit),  hence I only want to understand how the circuit looks when folding section wise.

Comment: For things like this instead of visualizing, you can just solve for it using mesh or nodal the entire circuit and pull the equivalent resistance out of the final equation.

Comment: `I can combine resistor at between 1-2 and 7-8` do you want to short 2 with 8 ?

Comment: You may short 2 to 5 to 8 or open both resistors as the voltage is same for 2 & 8. ok? Now it is a simple (R+R)//(r+r) with a symmetrical midpoint

Comment: @across No I mean to connect 1 to 7 and 2 to 8 , then I can make resistor between those two edges are paralel for that I get some resulting resistance, I can't seem to figure out how to depict the resultant

Comment: I understand that way of doing it @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 but I just want to know how the way of combining I stated would look like

Comment: yes. 0 Ohm short is allowed for these values and so is folding or superposition to reduce it, instead of doing Thevenin or matrix method. because of symmetry.